# Pandas: CSV header and data row size mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is it possible to instruct Pandas to ignore columns which positions are exceeding header size?

```
import pandas

with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write("datetime,A\n")
    csv_file.write("2018-10-09 18:00:07, 123\n")

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)
```

gives the answer:

```
              datetime    A
0  2018-10-09 18:00:07  123
```

However loading CSV file with more data columns, that defined in header:

```
with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write("datetime,A\n")
    csv_file.write("2018-10-09 18:00:07, 123, ABC, XYZ\n")

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)
```

returns:

```
                        datetime     A
2018-10-09 18:00:07 123      ABC   XYZ
```

Pandas shifts headers to the rightmost position of data.

I need different behavior. I'd like pandas to ignore data rows, which goes beyond the header.

**Note**: I can't enumerate columns, as it's a generic use case. Due to some independent from my code reason sometimes there is more data, that expected. I'd like to ignore the extra data.

Comment: ignore rows, or ignore columns?

Answer (score 2):

It seems Pandas realizes there are too many columns compared to the actual header, and it assumes the first two (data) columns are the (multi) index.

Specify the data columns to be read with the `usecols` parameter in `read_csv`:

```
import pandas

with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write("datetime,A\n")
    csv_file.write("2018-10-09 18:00:07, 123, ABC, XYZ\n")

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=[0,1]) 
print(df)
```

yields

```
              datetime    A
0  2018-10-09 18:00:07  123
```

Comment: It need a little more code, but your advice does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @RyszardStyczynski Given your example code, this should be enough. I guess you mean to say that your actual code & data requires a bit more work. But if this code does not work for the code in your question, let me know: perhaps I've overlooked something or there is something off.

Comment: you are right. I've just implemented quite opposite situation: when header is longer than data. It's not necessary as pandas supports it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Now the code shows answer to the question.

```
with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write("datetime,A\n")
    csv_file.write("2018-10-09 18:00:07, 123, ABC, XYZ\n")

with open("test.csv") as csv_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(csv_file):
        if i == 0:
            headerCount = line.count(",") + 1
            colCount = headerCount
        elif i == 1:
            dataCount = line.count(",") + 1  
        elif i > 1:
            break
if (headerCount < dataCount):
    print("Warning: Header and data size mismatch. Columns beyond header size will be removed.")
    colCount=headerCount

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=range(colCount))
print(df)
```

produces:

```
Warning: Header and data size mismatch. Columns beyond header size will be removed.
              datetime    A
0  2018-10-09 18:00:07  123
```

Answer (score -1):

To make the question complete, this the code which does the trick:

```
with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write("datetime,A, B, C\n")
    csv_file.write("2018-10-09 18:00:07, 123\n")

with open("test.csv") as csv_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(csv_file):
        if i == 0:
            headerCount = line.count(",") + 2
        elif i == 1:
            dataCount = line.count(",") + 2  
            if (headerCount != dataCount):
                print("Warning: Header and data size mismatch. Columns beyond header size will be removed.")
        elif i > 1:
            break


df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=range(dataCount-1))
print(df)
```

gives correct pandas object.

```
Warning: Header and data size mismatch. Columns beyond header size will be removed.
              datetime    A
0  2018-10-09 18:00:07  123
```